# Basic ReWrite Rule Request that is not a redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The user types the following into the browser and this remains the url in the browser:

```
xyz.com/info/x/
```

Internally this becomes:

```
xyz.com/x/
```

What I have is:

```
RewriteRule info/x/ http://xyz.com/x/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Problem with the above:

This is a redirect but I desire the browser to still show xyz.com/info/x/

No need for variables, I just want to handle one case.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the hostname and the `R` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^info/x/ /x/ [L,NC]
```

Or to be more general

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^info/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```